# Having problem with the Logic of the given question. Should I use an Array?

Tags: logic

Given the consecutive scores of a cricket match, calculate the total runs scored, the number of wickets, the extras, the runs scored by each batsman, the number of overs bowled. Notes: wkt - wicket, wd - wide ball, add one run to the scoreboard, bowl again, lb - leg bye, and nb - no-ball, add one run to the scoreboard, bowl again. The sample input is - 1 0 1wd 0 3 2 0 0 2nb 0wkt 6 1 0 4 and sample output is - total runs scored: 20, number of wickets: 1, extras: 2, scores by batsmen: 1st batsmen: 3 runs; 2nd batsmen: 8 runs; 3rd batsmen: 7 runs.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/8517948). You are encouraged to make an attempt. If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an Object, like this (I'm using javascript):

```
function myFunc() {
    return {
       scores : [],
       addScore : function(number){
          this.scores.push(number)
       }
       totalScore : function() {
          console.log(this.scores.reduce(a, b => a + b))
       }
    }
}
```

something like that

Answer (score 0):

The explanation how calculation is done I have mentioned, possibly coding part is not asked I guess, if coding is asked, entire score board is to be designed.
The calculation goes likes this -
The total score is 20 obtained.
The sample input is given for just two overs,
For first over it will 7
Second over it will be 13

I have attached an excel sheet image for the reference
[Sol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwXzX.jpg)